# MatLab - retype double to Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I need to retype the `array of double` to the `net`.

I have a code from: https://github.com/jwyang/face-alignment, but I can't make it work.
The error is in the function `train` from the file `globalregression.m` which requires as a first argument a data type `net`.

---

#### My attempts

At first I was trying to retype it with the `tonndata` function, but it didn't help because `tonndata` retyped `deltashapes` to `cell`:

```
parfor o = 1:size(deltashapes, 2)
    model = train(tonndata(deltashapes(:, o),true,false), sparse(binaryfeatures), param);
    W_liblinear(:, o) = model.w';
end
```

Then I ran into a function `feedforwardnet`, but I don't know how to pass my data from the variable `deltashapes`.

---

#### Report of the error

```
Error using globalregression>(parfor body) (line 48)
An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for 'train'.  This might be because the file containing 'train' is not
accessible on the workers.  Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required files to be attached.  See the
documentation for 'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details.

Error in globalregression (line 47)
parfor o = 1:size(deltashapes, 2)

Error in train_model (line 227)
    [W, Data] = globalregression(binfeatures, Data, Param, s);

Caused by:
    Undefined function 'train' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

---

#### My question

I need an advice about retyping double array to the neural net datatype in a simple way. I'm a total beginner with MatLab, so I'd appreciate a little more thorough explanation, if possible.

---

#### Links

- `tonndata` function - *www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/tonndata.html*
- `feedforwardnet` function - *www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html*
- `train` function - *www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html*